# How to compare two rdds using scala+spark.? There is no key in both the rdds?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, rdd, scala-collections

I want to compare data in two RDDs. How can I iterate and compare field data in one RDD with field data in another RDD. below Eg files:`

```
File1 
 f1  f2       f3    f4    f5      f6  f7
 1 Nancyxyz 23456 12:30 NEWYORK 9000 xyz 
 2 ranboxys 12345 12:30 NEWYORK 9000 xyz

 File2
 f1  f2       f3    f4    f5      f6  f7
 2 ranboxys 12345 12:30 NEWYORK 9000 xyz
 1 markalan 23456 12:30 LONDON  7000 xyz 
 3 Loyleeie 45678 12:40 London  9001 abc
```

In the above both files having 1st 2 records are same but the sequential order is different.
 Now i want to compare both the rdds and print only differ record i.e,

```
 File2
 3 Loyleeie 45678 12:40 London  9001 abc
```

I dont want to get first 2 records in both the rdds because both are same but order is different
 Can you please explain how to do that with using rdds in scala

I tried somany options like subtract and while loop. but no luck

I just changed in "file2"   2nd record now i want to print 2nd record and 3rd record in file2 and modified fields. I dont know which field is changed , it just compare file1 if it is not matched then print differ records and print in another line what are the fields are changed

Comment: Have you tried converting the RDDs to DataFrames and then use the `except` method?

Comment: @maasg thanks alot for sharing your thouts  i got that. It is not getting only 3rd differ record i am getting 2 records in file2                                                       1 Nancyxyz 23456 12:30 NEWYORK 9000 xyz 
 3 Loyleeie 45678 12:40 London  9001 abc i didnt get it whats wrong in substract function. Is there any other way .

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `File1` and `File2` are of type :`RDD[String]`, following operation will contain all elements in `File2` but not in `File1`

```
scala> val File1 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("File1.txt")

scala> val File2 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("File2.txt")

scala> File2.subtract(File1).collect
res0: Array[String] = Array(" 3 Loyleeie 45678 12:40 London  9001 abc")
```

Here name is the 2nd field in the string (trim the space initially)

```
scala> File2.subtract(File1).map { x => x.split(" ")(2) }.collect
res1: Array[String] = Array(Loyleeie)
```

if tab is your seperator, replace it accordingly

Comment: @Nathon, probably you should provide the approach that you have tried so far and indicate the area where you are struggling, then we can expand more on top of that.